# How do I know my Citi credit card account number for setting up a Virtual Account Number?

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, online-banking, citi, virtual-credit-card

I have a credit card from Citibank, and I want to create an Online Account¹ (a virtual credit card number) but it asks me for my "Credit Card Account Number". Upon entering my credit card number (without dashes) it fails with the error "Your entries do not match our records".

Why is that?

- Is my "Account Number" different from my credit card number?
- Do I have a separate website per country which has records for my credit card number?

¹ *Link removed by admin.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for joining, and thanks for your question!

From what I can tell, yes, the site you originally linked to (which I removed) appears to be in the United States and therefore likely intended for U.S. cardholders only.  Your profile indicates you are in the U.K.  **Most banks and credit card companies do maintain separate systems per country, for legal reasons.**

Anyway, **for your own security** I suggest you contact your card issuer's support telephone number and request the correct U.K. cardholder web site address from them directly.

**In general,** you don't want to be guessing or searching for the web site address for your credit card company or bank's online self-service application.  There are often "impostor" web sites out there that just want your credit card number!

Instead, you should obtain the web site addresses for your financial services from **trusted** sources only; i.e. direct from your bank or card issuer, such as on your printed statement, or through their help line, or linked-to from their known-good home page.

Finally, I do believe that your credit card number and account number are one and the same thing.

Comment: Good point Chris.  Some cards are even separating the card number from the logon process and opting for a userID and passphrase.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer, Chris. I'll contact my bank via phone / email and see if the same service (Virtual Account) is available in my country.

Comment: @user145 You managed to make it work? You got it yet? I am in similar situation. What's the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Just consult with the firm which was issued the card or you can take the help of their customer support which would help you give the information which you are looking for.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this answer adds anything to the existing question which was answered sufficiently a few years ago.

Comment: -1 Would downvote again